# Run assert inside event

Tags: testing, casperjs

I have the following:

```js
casper.then(function addToBag(){
    this.evaluate(function (){
        //register sub method - then emit custom event
        mns.msg.sub("/ajax/success/addToCart" + $("[name=productCode]").val(), function (response) {
            casper.emit('addToCart.loaded');
        });
        //trigger add to cart click
        $('.product-selection input[type=submit]').click();
    });
});
```

The click trigger activates the emit, inside the event function:

```js
casper.on("addToCart.loaded", function checkAddToCartResponse(){
    console.log("Added");
    test.assert(true,'Add to cart successful');
}),
```

However, it doesn't seem to run - is this the correct way of running a test when an event has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is not emitted because there is no `casper` instance inside the page context (inside the `evaluate` context).

You would need to set some flag that the event was emitted.

```js
casper.then(function addToBag(){    
    this.evaluate(function (){
        //register sub method - then emit custom event
        window.casperEventEmitted = null;
        mns.msg.sub("/ajax/success/addToCart" + $("[name=productCode]").val(), function (response) {
            window.casperEventEmitted = 'addToCart.loaded';
        });
        //trigger add to cart click
        $('.product-selection input[type=submit]').click();
    });
});
// wait here
```

and then wait for the event to be set

```js
var timeout = 10000; // msec, some sensible timeout for your event
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.getGlobal('casperEventEmitted') == 'addToCart.loaded';
}, function then() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        window.casperEventEmitted = null; // reset for next time
    });
    this.test.pass("Event triggered");
}, function onTimeout(){
    this.test.fail("Event triggered");
}, timeout);
```

Of course it would be nicer to manage the events in a queue and not as a single string.

The good thing is that there is no break out from the control flow as it would happen with a custom event like in the case of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162498/1816580).

Comment: thanks. I'd just figured it out - in the `waitFor` function you can actually use: 

`this.getGlobal('casperEventEmitted') == 'addToCart.loaded'`, without doing another `evaluate` on the page

Answer (score 1):

Use inside the `evaluate` callback:

```js
console.log("casper-event:add:[1234]");
```

then can do it like this (not tested):

```js
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
   if(msg.indexOf("casper-event:" == 0))
   {
       var event = msg.replace(/^casper-event:/, '').replace(/:.*$/, '');
       var result = JSON.parse(msg.replace(/^casper-event:.*?:/, ''));
       this.emit(event, result);
   }
});

casper.on('add'........
```